# Invalid Argument error with DoCmd.TransferSpreadhseet command?

Tags: excel, vba

As part of my script, I have the line:

```
Call objAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acImport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "MailMergeTable", strExcelPath, _
True, Worksheets("MailMerge").Range("A:K"))
```

Where objAccess has been set as `New Access.Application`. However, I'm getting an argument invalid error for what I believe is my range. Is there something very minor I'm missing here?

Comment: Try changing `Worksheets("MailMerge").Range("A:K"))` to just `"A1:K10"` as a test

Comment: For some reason, doing this just defaults to the first sheet in the workbook. Even if I activate `"MailMerge"` immediately beforehand. At the moment, I'm using `"MailMerge!"`, but in some cases this has more than 244 columns.